# How to redirect to other Screen without pressing button/link in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `@react-navigation/native` library for navigation. Now scenario is that I want to navigate to other screen after in `setTimeout`. I don't want to stack the page so I'm not usning `native-stack`. I have tried below code but it is not redirecting to `HomeScreen`

**`App.tsx`**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';

const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();
function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}

export default function App() {

  // after 3 seconds it should redirect to HomeScreen
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate(HomeScreen, {})
      //navigate('HomeScreen', {})
    }, 3000)
  })

  return (
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>
  );
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params); ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a state to know what screen to render, when that state change you must change screen.

If you dont wanna stack the screen you can use the reset, another way you must use an `if` to decide it.. for example to first case using reset https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigation-actions/#reset

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  // after 3 seconds it should redirect to HomeScreen
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.dispatch(
       CommonActions.reset({
         index: 1,
         routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
       })
     );
    }, 3000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>
  );
}
```

For second example (and correct IMHO)

```
export default function App() {
  const [changeScreen, setChangeScreen] = useState(false)

  // after 3 seconds it should redirect to HomeScreen
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setChangeScreen(true)
    }, 3000)
  }, [])

  return (
    changeScreen ? 
    <Home /> :
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>
  );
}
```

Comment: how to pass 'HomeScreen' component to route. 
`routes: [{ name: 'HomeScreen' }],` because if I do like this then it throws an error
` {"index":1,"routes":[{}]} was not handled by any navigator`

Comment: Can you try with `index: 0` ?, May the router think that you are trying to reset to a sub-screen, but you home-screen usually is the first screen (index: 0)